# Python: curl -d json will not work without apostrophe

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl

I have to send the curl exact in that form to get a response in cli

```
curl -d '{"id":0,"params":["aa:aa:00:00:00:00",["mixer","volume","80"]],"method":"slim.request"}' http://localhost:9000/jsonrpc.js
curl -d '{"id":0,"params":["aa:aa:00:00:00:00",["playlist","play","/home/pi/mp3/File.mp3"]],"method":"slim.request"}' http://localhost:9000/jsonrpc.js
```

Running the command above in my script, I get a syntax error for the apostrophe

```
  File "./updateTimers.py", line 126
    strVolume = curl -d '{"id":0,"params":["aa:aa:00:00:00:00",["mixer","volume","80"]],"method":"slim.request"}' http://localhost:9000/jsonrpc.js
                                                                                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If I change apostrophes and quotation than my python script does not like the syntax also. Would be happy any advice. At least I need to run both commands one by one.

```
strVolume = curl -d '{"id":0,"params":["aa:aa:00:00:00:00",["mixer","volume","80"]],"method":"slim.request"}' http://localhost:9000/jsonrpc.js
strPlayMP3Command = curl -d '{"id":0,"params":["aa:aa:00:00:00:00",["playlist","play","/home/pi/adhan/mp3/Adhan-Makkah.mp3"]],"method":"slim.request"}' http://localhost:9000/jsonrpc.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the `curl -d ...` to be a string in Python. To do this, you will also have to wrap `curl` in quotes: `strVolume = "curl -d '{\"id\": 0, ...}' ..."`. Make sure you escape the quotes inside.

Comment: The escapes did it. Tested before with the quotes and it was not correct. Thank you!

Comment: you can also use triple quotes: open and close your otest quotes wity. '''   or """ : this way you can include any number of apostrophes or double quotes in your string, without having to manually escape anything.